# Converting dictionary of array to single pandas data frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have got this dictionary(pred). The dictionary contains numpy arrays.

```
pred.keys()       
dict_keys([0, 1])  #keys of the dictionary
pred.values()   #### values of the array nested in dictionary 
dict_values([array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       ...,
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32), array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [0.],
       ...,
       [0.],
       [0.],
       [0.]], dtype=float32)])
I want to convert it into a data frame with each column showing the values of array for the dictionary key
```

Comment: Can you try `pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in pred.items()}, axis=1)` ?

Comment: Super, added to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in pred.items()}, axis=1)
```

If need only first column of DataFrame:

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v)[0] for k, v in pred.items()}, axis=1)
```